# All required inputs turn red when adding a dynamic formControl in a formArray

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

All required inputs turn red upon add of a formcontrol

Here is my working example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-emman-sample?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: what's your problem ?

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button click triggers a submit event on your form, which causes the form fields to validate.

You can check this with i.e. the Chrome developer tools under `Sources -> Event Listener Breakpoints -> Control -> Submit`

You could simply change the button type to `button` to prevent the event from being fired. (default is `submit`) According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

> If your buttons are not for submitting form data to a server, be sure
>   to set their type attribute to button. Otherwise they will try to
>   submit form data and to load the (nonexistent) response, possibly
>   destroying the current state of the document.

```
  <button mat-mini-fab type="button" color="primary" matSuffix (click)="addElem(control.key)" class="addBtn"
              *ngIf="i === 0">+</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, ill accept this answer